# Dynamically write text files from larger data-frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-frame which looks something like this:

```
df<-rbind(c(1,0,1,0,1,NA),c(1,0,0,1,1,NA),c(1,0,0,0,0,NA),c(1,1,1,1,1,NA),c( 2,0,1,1,1,1),c(2,1,1,0,0,0),c(2,0,0,0,0,1),c(2,1,1,1,1,1),c(2,0,0,0,0,0))
colnames(df)<-c("Team","A","B","C","D","E")
print(df)

Team    A    B    C    D    E
 1      0    1    0    1    NA
 1      0    0    1    1    NA
 1      0    0    0    0    NA
 1      1    1    1    1    NA
 2      0    1    1    1    1
 2      1    1    0    0    0
 2      0    0    0    0    1
 2      1    1    1    1    1
 2      0    0    0    0    0
```

I would like to dynamically write each team result as a text file where the name of each file corresponds to the team number and is written without the NAs (each file only contains its respective 0s and 1s.  Such that the final result looks like

```
"1.txt"
 0    1    0    1 
 0    0    1    1 
 0    0    0    0 
 1    1    1    1
"2.txt"
 0    1    1    1    1
 1    1    0    0    0
 0    0    0    0    1
 1    1    1    1    1
 0    0    0    0    0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `by` function is good for this, it splits a data.frame by factor level and applies a function to each group (see `?by`).

In your case you could use something like:

```
by(df, df$Team, function(x)
  write.table(x, sep = "\t", file = paste0(unique(x$Team), ".txt")))
```

Expanded based on comment:

```
by(df, df$Team, function(x){

  # drop columns if all are NA
  subset <- x[,colSums(is.na(x)) < nrow(x)]

  # drop team column and write groups to individual files
  write.table(subset[,-1], sep = "\t", 
    file = paste0(unique(x$Team), ".txt"),
    col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

  })
```

Comment: This is almost perfect; however, I would just like the final text files to have the numbers (i.e., no team column or A,B,C,D,E column headers).  Also I only want each text file numbers corresponding to the number of people in each team.  In other words no NAs.  For example, the first team's text file would only be a four by four file of 1s and 0s. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (`df` is you `data.frame`)

```
df<- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,0,1,0,1,NA),c(1,0,0,1,1,NA),c(1,0,0,0,0,NA),c(1,1,1,1,1,NA),c( 2,0,1,1,1,1),c(2,1,1,0,0,0),c(2,0,0,0,0,1),c(2,1,1,1,1,1),c(2,0,0,0,0,0)))
colnames(df)<-c("Team","A","B","C","D","E")

out <- split(df , f = df$Team)
n_teams <- length(unique(df$Team))
for (i in 1:n_teams) {
  eval(parse(text = paste0("write.table(out[[", i, "]], \"C:/Test/", i, ".txt\", sep=\"\t\",row.names=FALSE)")))
}
```

If you post reproducible data, I can further help you...

Comment: I added reproducible data.  Your proposed solution is yielding a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't have enough data for it be particularly slow, but I will keep that in mind in the future.